# Ktor and Android - Session Time Limit

Tags: android, session, session-cookies, ktor

I've successfully set a Time-Limit for a Session on my Ktor server. Now the session no longer lives for **7 days** (which is a default value), now it's life span is equals to: **'Session'**:

```
fun Application.configureSession() {
    install(Sessions) {
        val secretEncryptKey = hex("00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff")
        val secretAuthKey = hex("02030405060708090a0b0c")
        cookie<UserSession>(
            name = "USER_SESSION",
            storage = directorySessionStorage(File(".sessions"))
        ) {
            cookie.maxAgeInSeconds = 0
            transform(SessionTransportTransformerEncrypt(secretEncryptKey, secretAuthKey))
        }
    }
}
```

When Session life span is equals to 'Session', it means that the session should be automatically cleaned up immediately after the browser, for example is closed, on the client side. In this case I'm using Android app for a client, and whenever I close my app, I'm expecting to terminate/close that session and remove it from the server automatically. But sadly it's still available on my server, inside a .sessions folder. I'm able to remove it only after I explicitly call clear function from my server, to clear that session.

Is there any solution for me to make my Ktor server do a cleanup, and remove the session by default whenever I close my Android app and terminate the connection?

Comment: The simplest solution would be having a cron job that scans all the files in the session directory and removes those that have a modification time earlier than the current time by some amount. Just to note, a client shouldn't try to explicitly remove a session from the server because it's an internal detail of the server.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Is there any official documentation on how to combine cron job with my Ktor server to achieve that goal of removing sessions after a certain amount of time after the file has been modified? Btw thank you for answering to my question. :)

Comment: I don't think you need to interact with a Ktor server to remove sessions' files. Just write a script that will clean them up.